# Query with sort() and limit() in Spring Repository interface

Tags: spring-data, mongodb-java

I'm new to Spring Data with MongoDB and would like to have an automagically generated query method inside my MongoRepository extension interface which requires filtering, sorting and limiting.

The query looks like this:

```
// 'created' is the field I need to sort against

find({state:'ACTIVE'}).sort({created:-1}).limit(1)
```

The repository interface looks like this:

```
public interface JobRepository extends MongoRepository<Job, String> {
    @Query("{ state: 'ACTIVE', userId: ?0 }")
    List<Job> findActiveByUserId(String userId);

    // The next line is the problem, it wont work since
    // it's not in the format @Query expects
    @Query("find({state:'ACTIVE'}).sort({created:-1}).limit(1)")
    Job findOneActiveOldest();

    ...
}
```

I know that one can add a Sort argument to a query method in order to get sorting but the problem is limiting the results to just a single object. Is this possible to do without having to write a custom JobRepositoryImpl?

Thanks

Edit:

Example of what I am looking for:

```
@Query("{ state:'ACTIVE', $orderby: {created:-1}, $limit:1 }")
Job findOneActiveOldest();
```

or

```
@Query("{ state:'ACTIVE' }")
@Sort("{ created:-1 }")
@Limit(1)
Job findOneActiveOldest();
```

But this obviously doesn't work :(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
public interface JobRepository extends MongoRepository<Job, String> {

  @Query("{ state : 'ACTIVE' }")
  Page<Job> findOneActiveOldest(Pageable pageable);
}
```

and using it:

```
// Keep that in a constant if it stays the same
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created"));
Job job = repository.findOneActiveOldest(request).getContent().get(0);
```

Comment: I was so busy looking for a short and simple query-like solution that I didn't bother to examine the Pageable class and realize that this in combination with Sort sort-of wraps the .sort() and .limit() functionalities of a mongo query.

Comment: I know this is the old thread, but is it possible to say in that case do not count the total number of items in the collection, because Page is returned and you do this under the hood (so there are 2 queries: one for data and one for count), I know about @QueryHints(forCounting = false) or return List instead of Page, but it works inside interface, is there any alternative of @QueryHints in case of repository.doSomething()?

Comment: That only works for the 1st page.  If the paging parameters are passed through from a controller, say, then the sort order may not always be maintained.   There needs to be a way to bake it into the repository, same as when using Spring Data repository query method names (which just get too long to work with more complex filter criteria).   But it appears to be the best you can do!

Comment: new PageRequest() is deprecated so i used PageRequest.of()

Comment: As @TimeTraveler mentioned new PageRequest() is now deprecated. Instead use `PageRequest request = PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.Direction.DESC, "created");`

Answer (score 9):

Just adding a correction to Oliver's answer, it's `Direction.DESC` and not `Directions.DESC` and the order of the params is wrong.

Change :

```
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort("created", Directions.DESC));
```

to:

```
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "created"));
```

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Or edit the original answer, but now that I think about it, new users don't have the rep to comment OR edit.

Comment: @Sinatr see [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) on meta, particularly the "Editing Code in Answers" section. TL;DR: SO is a reference resource, not a game; editing is encouraged if it produces improvement; all edits are logged and anyone can review history.

Comment: I need a reputaion of 50+ to comment on the answer I wanted to clarify, so please advise exactly how I was supposed to make this clarification.

Comment: Thanks! The code worked for me with a minor change: Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Direction.ASC, "name"), new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "fID")));

Comment: How to use above logic if I already have Page<Job> findOneActiveOldest(Pageable pageable); method implemented for another purpose, so implementing same will be Duplicate method in type VisitRepository. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the answer, in the latest version of springboot, this is how you will create the PageRequest object:

```
PageRequest request = PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created"));
```