# Spring data mongoRepository Query sort

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I was looking to see how I could introduce a sort into a Query annotation in a repository method that I have.
I already saw this code in Google and here, but I could not make it works

```
@Query("find({state:'ACTIVE'}).sort({created:-1}).limit(1)")
    Job findOneActiveOldest();

@Query("{ state:'ACTIVE', $orderby: {created:-1}, $limit:1 }")
Job findOneActiveOldest();
```

I know that with pagination I can make it, but in some cases I don't need paginate, so I was wondering how to make it with Query annotation.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What's the problem? Why can't you make it not work?

Comment: JSONParse Exception in the case of the first one, and the second one dont return anything.

Comment: Isn't it your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067169/query-with-sort-and-limt-in-spring-repository-interface

Comment: No, take a look of the second answer of that question and read carefully my question/response

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do it with @Query annotation. If you dont need to paginate you can just make your repository method use Sort parameter:

```java
@Query("{ state:'ACTIVE' }")
Job findOneActive(Sort sort);
```

and use it:

```java
yourRepository.findOneActive(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created"))
```

Comment: Is a good solution thanks!. Still I cannot believe how bas is Query annotation for Mongo.

Comment: That's true there is still place for improvement there. Good thing is that Spring sources are on github so you can always code an enhancement and create pull request with it

Comment: What if I do need to paginate?

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak how to add limit to this. please advice

Comment: If you use limit and offset it will not work, it's work around.

Comment: Now Limit and sorting is possible in @Query

Answer (score 16):

Just use sort parameter of `@Query` annotation. 1 = ASC, -1 = DESC

```
    @Query(
        value  = ...,
        sort = "{'details.requestTime': -1}"
    )
```

Comment: How to perform group-by ?

Comment: It is the correct response, without work around! Excelent.

Answer (score 0):

if you also want to have pagination then use **Pageable** as method argument instead of Sort. Try below code:

```
@Query("{ state:'ACTIVE' }")
Job findOneActive(Pageable pageable);

yourRepository.findOneActive(new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"created")));
```