# Spring Mongo Paging with sorting with MongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pagination, spring-mongo, mongorepository

Document Structure - **message{obj_id,post_id,message_time,message_text}** and @key is **obj_id**.

Problem Statement: I just want that fetch all the data contains  **post_id: '*anything*'** with sorts on the basis of **message_time** and want custom paging in the result every time. Now I am implementing code mentioned below according to **link:**https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077534/9901300. But couldn't find where should I give different **post_id** every time to search result for.

Please look over below code.

```
public interface MessageMongoRepository extends 
MongoRepository<Message, String> {

@Query("{ 'post_id' : ?0 }")
Page<Message> findByPostIdSorted(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Override
public List<Message> getByPostId(String PostId, int page, int size) {
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    PageRequest request = new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "message_time"));
    messages = messageRepository.findByPostIdSorted(request).getContent();
    return messages;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for :

**Repository:**

```
@Query("{ 'post_id' : ?0 }")
Page<Message> findByPostId(String postId, Pageable pageable);
```

**Service**

```
messages = messageRepository.findByPostId(postId, request).getContent();
```

You can just pass the postId to the method defined in the repository

Comment: Thanks, Kency :) This is excactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Arpan Jain Welcome :)